# как обратится ко второму символу строки '123' в фу-и и вывести число 2 через console.log, не меняя код в самой функции

Tags: javascript

```
function exercise_10() {
    let my_string = '123';
    return my_string;
}
console.log(exercise_10()); // что прописать тут? чтобы вызвать число 2 из функции?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Доступ к символам](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access)

Существует два способа добраться до конкретного символа в строке. В первом способе используется метод `charAt()`:

```
return 'кот'.charAt(1); // вернёт "о"
```

Другим способом (введённым в ECMAScript 5) является рассмотрение строки как массивоподобного объекта, в котором символы имеют соответствующие числовые индексы:

```
return 'кот'[1]; // вернёт "о"
```

```js
function exercise_10() {
  let my_string = '123';
  return my_string;
}
console.log(exercise_10()[1]);
```

Тут мы обратились ко второму элементу строки. Не забываем, что в [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) счет начинается с 0.

Comment: Для тех, кто ничего не понял - в js к строкам можно обращаться как к массивам, то есть тут мы обратились ко второму элементу строки (не забываем, что счет начинается с 0 в программировании)

Answer (score 2):

```js
function exercise_10() {
  let my_string = '123';
  return my_string;
}
console.log(exercise_10().charAt(1));
```